# Can you have two functions with separate FPS values at the same time?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm working on a game that shows Python drawn images on the screen and occasionally the user needs to click and drag an item from an inventory to have some collision on the screen.

The main function of the game has: `clock.tick(60)`. I created a function that shows noise (like when a TV doesn't have reception) and at 60 FPS, it runs way too fast.  If I add a sleep, wait, delay, etc., it looks great, but, then dragging an item on the screen has a lot of lag.  I would prefer to not have the items lag at all, so I need to know how to slow down the noise function.

```py
def whitespace(surface, rect):
    pixel_size = 4
    pixel_length = rect.h / pixel_size
    pixel_height = rect.w / pixel_size
    start = rect.x

    pixel_grid = [[1]*int(pixel_height) for n in range(int(pixel_length))]

    colors = [(255, 255, 255), (205, 205, 205), (155, 155, 155), (100, 100, 100)]

    for row in pixel_grid:
        for col in row:
            color = random.randint(0, 3)
            surface.fill(colors[color], ((rect.x, rect.y), (pixel_size, pixel_size)))
            rect.x += pixel_size
        rect.y += pixel_size
        rect.x = start
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a function that can generate the a "whitespace" surface. The generated surface is returned from the function:

```py
def create_whitespace(rect):
    surface = pygame.Surface(rect.size)

    pixel_size = 4
    pixel_length = rect.h / pixel_size
    pixel_height = rect.w / pixel_size
    start = rect.x

    pixel_grid = [[1]*int(pixel_height) for n in range(int(pixel_length))]

    colors = [(255, 255, 255), (205, 205, 205), (155, 155, 155), (100, 100, 100)]

    for row in pixel_grid:
        for col in row:
            color = random.randint(0, 3)
            surface.fill(colors[color], (0, 0, pixel_size, pixel_size))
            rect.x += pixel_size
        rect.y += pixel_size
        rect.x = start

    return surface
```

Create another function which `blit`s the surface the the window:

```py
def draw_whitespace(surface, ws_surf, rect):
    surface.blit(ws_surf, rect)
```

Blit the surface to the window in every frame, but generate a new random "whitespace" surface less often. That causes that the same "whitespace" is draw for multiple frames:

```py
ws_cnt = 0
while True:

    # [...]

    if ws_cnt == 0:
        ws_surf = create_whitespace(rect)
    ws_cnt += 1
    if ws_cnt == 5: # 5 is just an example
        ws_cnt = 0
    draw_whitespace(screen, ws_surf, rect)

    # [...]
```

Comment: I kept getting reference errors: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ws_surf' referenced before assignment

Comment: OK! That did work... But instead of putting the counter in the first IF, I backed it up out of it, because once it was above zero, another whitespace wouldn't be created.  Now it seems to work, and is going more slowly, but it seems that every time it hits 0 again, the screen flashes... Not even sure how to explain.

Comment: @kennex Oh. Of course, my bad. The counter has to be incremented in any case.

Comment: Okay, this seems to be working, but two things now... 1) the blit isn't at 0,0 of the rect like expected... it's actually seemingly in a random position.  And 2) again, every so often, it flashes and blits almost at the bottom of the rect.  I have no idea why that is happening...